# how to make wordpress posts loop and replace the html output using jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

In my wordpress site, I have a page that has 3 sections. Every section contains posts from a specific category. I use this wordpress query to get the latest 3 posts in that category and load it in it's section(div). So, for "Novels" section, I use this query:

```
<? $novels = get_option('of_novels') ?>
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts('category_name=$novels&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="sliderunit">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="novelsslidertitle">
            <div class="arrow-left"></div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="cross" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/cross.png"/></a>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <h3>رواية</h3>
        </div>
    </div>                    
<?php endwhile;?>
```

and that gets me the latest 3 posts in #novels category. Now, I have some buttons. I want to write some jequery to loop on this category and get previous and next posts, and reloads the new queries content to that #novels div, replacing the old query code in the html using

```
$("<div/>").replaceWith("// Replace with a function to get the code of new output");
```

to act as a slider without using pagination and reloading the page? I hope my problem is well declared, I appreciate any helpful clues, links or references.

Comment: If you load the last 3 posts, and the user makes it to the 3rd post, do you want the next post to be the 4th?  Or do you want the user to not be able to go past the 3rd?

Comment: I want it to go to the 4th, 5th, 6th posts and so on

Comment: You might want to check this plugin out: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/infinite-scroll/

Comment: unfortunately this plugin is not what I need

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `$.replaceWith` is really what you need here.  You would just listen for when the user reaches a certain point, maybe the last in the currently loaded posts, or the second to last, then run `$.ajax()` or similar query, append that to your `#sliderunit` and it will make it so you be able to continue scrolling/sliding.  By appending and not replacing, you can go back and forth if you want without having to reload anything.  If you are concerned about memory management, you could use `$.remove()` at a certain threshold.

In case you need a little more info on how to do this, start by appending your new data, then using CSS manipulation such as `$.animate()` to perform the slide effect.  You can either use layers to hide things you don't want showing, or I guess you could also call `$.hide()` on blocks you don't want shown.

Comment: Can I have any link for a tutorial that would explain more? I am quite a beginner to jQuery